# Cómo actualizar proyecto local de GitHub

Tags: git, github, repositorio, git-merge

Tengo un proyecto privado en GitHub.

Estoy desarrollando en mi PC de escritorio y estoy haciendo pull sin problemas.

Tengo una laptop donde he clonado el repositorio sin problemas. Lo que quiero es estar desarrollando y subiendo cambios desde la de escritorio y visualizando cambios en la laptop.

En la laptop probé con `git fetch` y al parecer termina el proceso correctamente pero No veo cambios en el Sistema. Probé enseguida con `git merge` y no veo cambios.

He leído varias veces la documentación y comentarios en diversos sitios y no doy con la solución o comandos correctos.

`git merge` tengo entendido que es para actualizar cambios tanto en local o remoto. Pero en realidad no necesito actualiza el repositorio remoto desde la laptop. En la laptop solo quiero estar bajando actualizaciones para ver cambios y avances.

Any suggestion?  Soy novato con git

Comment: No porque `git fetch` solo descarga los cambios. `git pull` los descarga y los muestra. Si se te dificultan los comandos usa una interfaz gráfica como Github Desktop.

Comment: para sincronizar con el repo remoto se usa `git pull` en caso de que tengas varias ramas tendras que agregarle al final el nombre de esta. Para subir los datos comiteados se usa `git push` ten en cuenta que para hacer ambos procesos debes estar previamente autenticado con un llavero ssh en ambas computadoras. De lo contrario deberas hacer el repo publico y automatizarlo con un script para eliminar el folder y volver hacer el git clone cada cierto tiempo

Comment: El flujo "normal" es tener una rama _local_ que tiene una rama upstream del remoto.... Al estar en la rama local y hacer `git pull` git actualizaría la información del remoto y actualizaría la rama local (y el árbol de trabajo) con lo que hay en la rama remota

Comment: Si eres novato con Git, mejor usa Github Desktop y te ahorras dolores de cabeza. Ya luego aprendes lo otro.